# Quick conversion of mp4 to hls using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I need to convert huge video(around 2-4GB) using ffmpeg from mp4 to hls format.
The following takes very long to run, is there any quick conversion flag in ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i ad1.mp4 -strict -2 -profile:v baseline -level 3.0 -start_number 0 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename 'sample-%06d.ts' -f hls sample.m3u8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming ffmpeg is using the x264 encoder, change the preset.

```
ffmpeg -i ad1.mp4 -strict -2 -preset:v veryfast -profile:v baseline ...
```

This should increase speed by 100% for moderate difference in bitrate. There are other presets like `superfast` but filesize will increase appreciably.